# QGIS: Show line ELEV on hover or select?

Tags: qgis, elevation, altitude

I've installed the value tool plugin, but cannot figure out where it outputs. I tried map tips in qgis. How can I see the elevation of a line or selected point on hover or select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector layer, and ELEV is an atttribute (contour lines?) you should be able to use the [**Identify tool**](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html)

The **Value tool** plugin works with rasters.

It should open a dock window. If that isn't appearing, <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on a blank part of the toolbar and make sure you have a check against **Value Tool** in the menu.

[image: Value Tool plugin dock window]

In the dock window click on <kbd>Enable</kbd>. Now when you move the mouse over the canvas, it'll display values.

Thank you for pointing out this plugin - I hadn't seen it, and I'll find it very useful!

Comment: The identify tool will also show any "z" values present in vector data, if that's how the elevation is stored.